# Filtering rows on a csv with values that I have on a txt file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, filtering

So I have a csv file where I need to filter the rows based on the values that I have on a txt file. Is there an easy way to do this on pandas? The csv will have about 2000 rows and the txt file has about 400 data points. I need to generate a csv with rows that match the data on the txt file.

The CSV file looks like this:

```
Chromosome Gene Start End 
1 PERM1 5 6 
2 AGRN 7 10
3 MIB2 9 12
```

The Text file looks like

```
PERM1 
NADK 
GNB1
```

Thank you

Comment: You could do it with reindexing in python. However, without looking at the sample data, it is difficult to post an answer. Please modify your question according to https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

First read Text file into a list or tuple:

```
lines = tuple(open(filename, 'r'))
```

Then filter the lines exist in the text file:

```
df = read_csv('csvfile')
result = df[df['Chromosome Gene'].isin(lines)]
```

Answer (score 0):

easy enough using pandas read and filter functionality. I'm assuming you have an input .csv file called input_csv_file and a filter file called filter.csv. Input file has a column "filter_locatitons" and input_file has a column called "locations":

```
input_df = pd.read_csv('input_csv_file.csv')
filter_df = pd.read_csv('filter.csv')

filtered_df = input_df[[input_df['location'].isin(filter_df['filter_locations']]
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using mask and loading both the files in dataframes. Below code assumes your test file does not have a header and your csv file is space delimited

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('csvfile.csv', delimiter=' ')
df2 = pd.read_csv('textfile.txt', header=None)
df2.columns = ['Gene']

m = df1.Gene.isin(df2.Gene)
df3 = df1[m]
print(df3)
```